# pandas edit a cell value with itertuples

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I would like speed my code, so I don't like to use double for:
my code:

```
    for c in range(0, n-1):
        for l in range(0,n-c-1):
            df2.ix[l,c]=C_back(l,c,df)
```

I would like to use

```
for x in df.itertuples():
```

but I don't know how to modify a specific cell value.
thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using iteruples:

```
        for each in dt.itertuples():
            dt.loc[each.Index, 'column'] = value
```

Answer (score 2):

use `stack`

```
for mytuple, value in df.stack().iteritems():
    print(mytuple, value)
```

---

consider the `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(-1, 3), list('ABC'), list('XYZ'))
df
```

[image]

```
for mytuple, value in df.stack().iteritems():
    print(mytuple, value)

('A', 'X') 0
('A', 'Y') 1
('A', 'Z') 2
('B', 'X') 3
('B', 'Y') 4
('B', 'Z') 5
('C', 'X') 6
('C', 'Y') 7
('C', 'Z') 8
```

---

To set the values of `df`

```
for (i, j), value in df.stack().iteritems():
    df.set_value(i, j, value ** 2)

df
```

[image]

Comment: What if I want to set only the lower diagonal of my df, i.e (5,7,8) in the example, Thank you very much!

Comment: more complicated, what if I want to replace the cell value (B,Z) by (B,Y).value *2 and (C,Y) by (C,X).value *2 and (C,Z) by (C,Y).value*2.

Comment: set_value are not public api - yes they are not deprecated but discourage use