# Performances for different ways of accessing dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am just studying Python Pandas Data Frame and I saw

```
%timeit
```

then I compare a few Dataframe,
Below is an example of performances for different ways of accessing data frames that are highly relevant when the datasets become large.

so

```
%timeit data.ix[0,0]
```

10000 loops, best of 3: 159 µs per loop

```
%timeit data.loc[0,'nation']
```

10000 loops, best of 3: 158 µs per loop

```
%timeit data.iloc[0,0]
```

10000 loops, best of 3: 132 µs per loop

```
%timeit data.iat[0,0]
```

100000 loops, best of 3: 5.9 µs per loop

and you can see `data.iat[0,0]` hugely different from others.

My question is why `.iat` different than others and how is working?
Can we work with any data?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757389/loc-vs-iloc-vs-ix-vs-at-vs-iat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, don't use `ix`... it's use cases are more confusing than `iloc`/`loc` or `iat`/`at`.  [And `ix` will be deprecated](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14218)

Second, `get_value` is way quicker but isn't intended to be public API, though nothing stops you from using it.  [See @jeff's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40536854/2336654)

---

Now the meat of the answer:

`iloc` and `loc` accept array-like input... `iat` and `at` do not.  So if you are accessing a single point in the dataframe, by all means, use `iat` and `at`.  However, if you are looking to use boolean arrays or an array of positions or index values, you can't use `iat` or `at` so use `iloc` and `loc`